# Assign instance variables with local variables - Java

Tags: java, object, instance-variables, local-variables

When you assign the value of a local string into an instance variable of a class, does it create a new object (String)?

```
public void setNumber(String number){
    if(number == null || number.length() != 9)
        return;
    this.number = number;
}
```

Do this implicity works like this:

```
this.number = new String(number);
```

Comment: No. It refers to the same String instance

Comment: No, and you can easily check. == is used to test for the same instance. If you print the value of this.number == number on the next line you will see it prints true. If you try it with the new String(number) version, it will print false.

Comment: Since Java strings are immutable, there is never a reason to do `new String(str)` implicitly.

Comment: Java has always been a bad language to learn how objects and references work... You only handle references but you never see one. People should start with C++ and eventually switch to Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The important detail to understand is when you pass a `String` as a parameter to the `setNumber` method, you're not passing an object, you're passing a reference so when you do

```
this.number = number;
```

you're taking the reference passed as a parameter and then assigning it to the `this.number` variable.

There is no implicit object construction in the aforementioned statement.